# Java Runtime.getRuntime().exec not working with double quotes in command

Tags: java, gcloud, runtime.exec, google-cloud-dataproc

The below commands works fine in my terminal:

`gcloud` logging read `"logName=projects/logs/java.log AND labels.component=projet1 AND textPayload=\"End: of query.\"`

But returns null `inputstream` while executing through `Runtime.getRuntime().exec`

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process process = rt.exec(new String[]{"gcloud", "logging" ,"read" ,"logName=projects/logs/java.log AND labels.component=project1 AND textPayload=\"End: of query.\""});
BufferedReader is = new BufferedReader(new 
InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
```

**UPDATE:**
I have tried using processBuilder and my command arguments looks like :

Command is : [gcloud, logging, read, 'logName=projects/logs/java.log AND labels.component=project1 AND textPayload="End: of query." AND timestamp>"2018-11-15T15:12:11Z"']

But i get the following error on execution:

ERROR: (gcloud.logging.read) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Unparseable filter: syntax error at line 1, column 147, token '"2018-11-15T15:12:11Z"'

Comment: Have you tried it using a [`ProcessBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)?

Comment: What's null exactly, process.getInputStream() or the line when you read from the input stream? Did you also try process.getErrorStream()?

Comment: @deHaar Yes tried with processBuilder too .. but gettig exception while converting from inputstream to string RROR: (gcloud.logging.read) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Unparseable filter: syntax error at line 1, column 108, token ':';
syntax error at line 1, column 164, token ':'

Comment: If the colon is *unparseable*, then you should check if you can use a different text payload. Colons are not escapable... Try some charset codes instead of the colon directly, maybe.

Answer (score 3):

You need a double \ escaping, it's common in Java when we call another thing that's need escaping (regex or whatever)

try this (I only replaced \" with \\")

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process process = rt.exec(new String[]{"gcloud", "logging" ,"read"  
,"logName=projects/logs/java.log AND labels.component=project1 AND textPayload=\\\"End: of query.\\\""});
BufferedReader is = new BufferedReader(new 
InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
```

- \ : escape to \
- \" : escape to "
- so \\" will escape in runtime.exec to \"

Comment: My bad i have used \\ escape already but that does not seem to work. Tried with processBuilder too but geting the below exception while converting inputSTream to string .   ERROR: (gcloud.logging.read) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Unparseable filter: syntax error at line 1, column 108, token ':';
syntax error at line 1, column 164, token ':'

Comment: The whole "logName=...\"End: of query.\"" is quoted in gcloud, so it needs another layer of quote in Java, right?